# Fixing pesky "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter." error

Tags: typescript, trpc.io

I have the following Vue 3 `useTRPCQuery()` composable which lightly wraps tRPC.io's client.query() call, which aims to be type-aware and reactive.

My usage attempt is as follows:

```
export function useQuery(
  client: TRPCClient<AppRouter>,
  pathAndInput: [path: TPath, ...args: inferHandlerInput<TQueries[TPath]>]
) {
  const response = ref<inferQueryOutput<TPath>>()

  ;(async () => {
    const data = await client.query(*...pathAndInput*) # TS Error Here
    response.value = data
  })()

  return response
}
```

All works ok at runtime, but I'm seeing the following error around the `pathAndInput` tuple:

```
spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.
```

I've looked at potential fixes for this, such as passing in `path` and `...args` separately, e.g.,

```
export function useQuery(
  client: TRPCClient<AppRouter>,
  path: TPath,
  ...args: inferHandlerInput<TQueries[TPath]>
) {
  const response = ref<inferQueryOutput<TPath>>()

  ;(async () => {
    const data = await client.query(path, ...args)
    response.value = data
  })()

  return response
}
```

but I'd love to be able to have my usage of this composable as follows:

```
export const useTelescopes = (client: TRPCClient<AppRouter>) => {
  return {
    telescopes: useQuery(client, ['telescope.all', someExtraArgs])
  }
}
```

Is there something I am missing that can allow me to use a tuple in this way?

The full code for the useQuery reference is as follows:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

import type {
  ProcedureRecord,
  inferHandlerInput,
  inferProcedureInput,
  inferProcedureOutput
} from '@trpc/server'

import type { TRPCClient, TRPCClientErrorLike } from '@trpc/client'

import type { AppRouter } from '../somewhere/where/your/server/is/server.ts'

export type TQueries = AppRouter['_def']['queries']
export type TError = TRPCClientErrorLike<AppRouter>

export type inferProcedures<TObj extends ProcedureRecord<any, any, any, any, any, any>> = {
  [TPath in keyof TObj]: {
    input: inferProcedureInput<TObj[TPath]>
    output: inferProcedureOutput<TObj[TPath]>
  }
}

export type TQueryValues = inferProcedures<AppRouter['_def']['queries']>

export type TPath = keyof TQueryValues & string

/**
 *
 * This is a helper method to infer the output of a query resolver
 *
 */
export type inferQueryOutput<TRouteKey extends keyof AppRouter['_def']['queries']> = inferProcedureOutput<
  AppRouter['_def']['queries'][TRouteKey]
>

/**
 *
 * This is a helper method to infer the input of a query resolver
 *
 */
export type inferQueryInput<TRouteKey extends keyof AppRouter['_def']['queries']> = inferProcedureInput<
  AppRouter['_def']['queries'][TRouteKey]
>

export function useQuery(
  client: TRPCClient<AppRouter>,
  path: TPath,
  ...args: inferHandlerInput<TQueries[TPath]>
) {
  const response = ref<inferQueryOutput<TPath>>()

  ;(async () => {
    const data = await client.query(path, ...args)
    response.value = data
  })()

  return response
}
```

An example AppRouter type would be:

```
import * as trpc from '@trpc/server';

export const appRouter = trpc
  .router<Context>()
  // Create procedure at path 'hello'
  .query('hello', {
    resolve({ ctx }) {
      return {
        greeting: `hello world`,
      };
    },
  });

type AppRouter = typeof appRouter;
```

which should be queryable as the following:

```
useQuery(client, ['hello'])
```

Comment: please provide reproducible example with all imports

Comment: Hi @captain-yossarian. Thank you for your input. I believe this to be a question more of a typescript fundamentals than library specific.

Comment: Sure, but, for instance, I'd like to help and check whether my suggestion works, how do I do it ?

Comment: Yeh that's fair ... the AppRouter is type generated and very specific to what I've set up, but if you have used tRPC.io you can see how a server AppRouter can be setup. I will add as many relevant imports as possible.

Comment: Could you please share `AppRouter` type

Comment: I've added an example AppRouter, more information here: https://trpc.io/docs/router if needed.